# C++: High speed stack

Tags: c++, stack

As far as I assume, std::stack and all such 'handmade' stacks work much slower than stack which is applications one.

Maybe there's a good low-level 'bicycle' already? (Stack realization).

Or it's a good idea to create new thread and use it's own stack?

And how can I work directly with application stack? (asm {} only?)

Comment: When you're talking about stack it almost sounds like you're confusing a collection object with the memory model.  Is that so?

Comment: I hope not.  For some algorithms, you either have to implicitly use the CPU's stack by doing recursion, or explicitly building a stack as a data structure.  Other than that, the two aren't really comparable.

Comment: when you use recursion you do not use CPU's physical stack directly, i would say you use logical call stack that is then mapped to cpu. for different compilers or CPU architectures the physical implementation may vary.

Comment: Not actually. I just need some kind of structure with pop() and push() methods (only), working as fast as it is possible. So, it should be stack.

Comment: "As far as I assume..." Stop right there.

Comment: @Andrey: I agree, which is why I called the usage "implicit".  However, it's still true that using the CPU stack implicitly may be faster that explicitly creating a stack data structure.

Comment: Well, hand made stacks allocate it's data in heap, isn't it? So, it must be slower.

Comment: Why? Allocating takes a lot of time, but after that, heap memory is just as fast as the memory of the stack. (Because it's the same.)

Comment: @Minner: std::stack<> is merely an adaptor that provides a stack interface to the underlying sequence (vector, list, deque, etc).  You can change the underlying sequence's allocator if the default allocator is insufficient, e.g. std::stack<int, std::deque<int, YourAllocator> >.

Comment: @Georg, really? I knew, stack is in heap actually, but thought there's some kind of additional 'magic' there :)

Comment: Trying to guess what "magic" lies between the programmer's model and the hardware will only make the code slower, buggier and harder to maintain. Optimisation is best done through knowledge and measurement, with a clean, working implementation to start from and thorough test cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way in which `std::stack` is significantly slower than the processor stack is that it has to allocate memory from the free store. By default, it uses `std::deque` for storage, which allocates memory in chunks as needed. As long as you don't keep destroying and recreating the stack, it will keep that memory and not need to allocate more unless it grows bigger than before. So structure code like this:

```
std::stack<int> stack;
for (int i = 0; i < HUGE_NUMBER; ++i) 
    do_lots_of_work(stack); // uses stack
```

rather than:

```
for (int i = 0; i < HUGE_NUMBER; ++i)
    do_lots_of_work(); // creates its own stack
```

If, after profiling, you find that it's still spending too long allocating memory, then you could preallocate a large block so you only need a single allocation when your program starts up (assuming you can find an upper limit for the stack size). You need to get into the innards of the stack to do this, but it is possible by deriving your own stack type. Something like this (not tested):

```
class PreallocatedStack : public std::stack< int, std::vector<int> >
{
public:
    explicit PreallocatedStack(size_t size) { c.reserve(size); }
};
```

**EDIT:** this is quite a gruesome hack, but it is supported by the C++ Standard. More tasteful would be to initialise a stack with a reserved vector, at the cost of an extra allocation. And don't try to use this class polymorphically - STL containers aren't designed for that.

Using the processor stack won't be portable, and on some platforms might make it impossible to use local variables after pushing something - you might end up having to code everything in assembly. (That is an option, if you really need to count every last cycle and don't need portability, but make sure you use a profiler to check that it really is worthwhile). There's no way to use another thread's stack that will be faster than a stack container.

Comment: Obligatory: Inheriting from STL classes is bad. Also, there is no standard name by which the underlying container should be named. The correct solution is to pass a reserved vector into the constructor of `std::stack`.

Comment: According to the C++ Standard (23.2.3.3): `protected: Container c;`

Comment: But I agree that it's very distasteful, and I've added a note to that effect.

Comment: Gasp, I never knew that. Had it been private it would be named whatever, but it's protected. Strange since it has no virtual destructor...I wonder the reason for that.

Comment: @GMan: So that people like Mike can make us twitch.

Answer (score 4):

std::stack is a collection of c++ objects that have stack semantics. It has nothing to do with a thread's stack or the push and pop intructions in assembler code.

Which one are you trying to do

The 'assembler' stack is usually maintained by the hardware and required by various calling conventions, so you have no choice about how to 'allocate' it or 'manage' it. Some architectures have highly configurable stacks but you dont say what arch you are on

If you want a collection with stack semantics and you are writing in c++ then std::stack is your choice unless you can *prove* that its not fast enough

Comment: Heap allocations in STL are usually handled intelligently, and you can use APIs like `std::vector<T>::reserve` to let the application know beforehand a good starting allocation size. From there pushing can be done in amortized O(1), and popping O(1) as well.

Comment: @MInner - slower than what? There is nothing inherently slow about the heap. In fact most STL implementations have their own fast memory pool. If std::stack semantics is what you want, use it unless you can prove its too slow

Comment: std::stack<>'s data is allocated using the underlying sequence's allocator, which typically uses the heap.  You can always change the underlying sequence's allocator.

Comment: You can create a *stack* with an array that will be as fast as the *application* stack.  The application is only changing register (pointer) to next items when pushing and popping items.  Before using this technique, **profile** your code to see where the most time is spent and optimize that part.

Answer (score 3):

MInner, are you sure that stack operations are/can be bottlenecks of our application? if not, and i can bet for it, just use std::stack and forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea that a "handmade" stack is necessarily slower than the one used for function calls is fundamentally flawed. The two work sufficiently similarly that they will typically be close to the same speed. The biggest point that favors the hardware stack is that it's used often enough that the data at or close to the top of that stack will almost always be in the cache. Another stack that you create usually won't be used as often, so there's a much better chance that any given reference will end up going to main memory instead of the cache.

In the other direction, you have a bit more flexibility in allocating memory for your stack. You can create a specialized allocator *just* for your stack. When the hardware stack overflows, it normally allocates memory using the kernel allocator. The kernel allocator is usually tuned quite carefully, so it's usually pretty efficient -- but it's also extremely general purpose. It can't be written just to do stack allocation really well; it has to be written to do any kind of allocation at least reasonably well. In the process, its ability to do one thing exceptionally well often suffers a bit.

It's certainly possible to create a stack that's arbitrarily slow, but there's no fundamental reason that your stack *can't* be just as fast (or possibly even faster) than the one provided by the (usual) hardware. I'll repeat though: the single biggest reason for it to be slower is cache allocation, which simply reflects usage.

Comment: I wonder if we dig really, really deep into the machine level, if, aside from the potential cache-related benefits of the hardware stack's usage frequency, if it might also have a small edge due to stack pointer registers like `esp/rsp` on x86/x64 being constantly reserved specifically for that purpose. That's getting extremely micro though, but it might have some relevance in dispersed functionality with latency-type rather than throughput-type concerns.

Comment: At least from what I've seen, it's actually a bit of the opposite: the constant  use of the stack pointer prevents some instruction level parallelism (but usually not a whole lot).

Comment: I see -- that's really interesting! It would make that hand-rolled stack potentially faster in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement.
If you want to push a userdefined data type on stack, you will need  'handmade' stacks

for others say, you want to push integers, chars, or pointers of objects you can use
asm
{
  push
  pop
}
but dont mess it up